# Google API returning different PlaceId that what I'm sending

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to get the address using the placeId

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=EiNBaGEgTWFjYXYgUGFya3dheSwgTmVlZGxlcywgQ0EsIFVTQQ&key=xxx
```

But in the response I'm getting a different placeId, in above case I'm getting

```
EiZBaGEgTWFjYXYgUGt3eSwgTmVlZGxlcywgQ0EgODkwMjksIFVTQSJIKkYKFAoSCd8xX6BuR86AEfJPr9Qtl6MIEhQKEgkzijXhciPOgBHzlA3hF6hfIBoYCgoNhyLfFBXihae7EgoNgO3fFBXfkai7
```

why it is not same?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Maps Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) documentation,

> A place ID is a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place. The length of the identifier may vary.

Even though it may differ, it will still resolve to the same location when you use it in the APIs.